# Private folders or multiple accounts

Tags: box-api

I'm developing a service and the users can upload documents to Box with the API. I want every user to have there own private space and not be able see or upload files to other spaces. How is this possible? By multiple accounts with Enterprise? I don't want the users to activate/create an account, so my thought was to only use folders and set one folder (and subfolders) per user. What is the best solution?

I'm not going to use the Box interface at all, only the API and my own website to view/upload/download files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain why you have chosen Box for this application?  Not to undermine Box as a service, but if you are just looking for a cloud based storage backend something like Amazon's S3 would probably be a better fit for what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I will use Google Cloud Storage instead. Now I know better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [token](http://developers.box.com/docs/#tokens) endpoint in the v2 API.  It creates and provides access to a single folder on per-user basis, even if that user doesn't already have a Box account.  Caveats: you'd need to know the user's email address, and I don't know how long-lived those private folders are intended to be.